# How to filter url links with criteria via beautifulsoup? is it possible? YES indeed

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

There are always some new posts in any forum. The one I visited gives a "new" sticker to the post. How do i filter and retrieve the URLs with new stickers? Tricky...

I usually just grabbed off first page. But it seems unprofessional. Actually there are also author and date stickers in each section. Can these be filtering criteria via beautifulsoup? I am feeling so much to learn.

This is the DOM:

```
<!-- 三級置頂分開 -->
<tbody id="stickthread_10432064">
<tr>
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10432064-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
<td class="icon">
                                                                    </td>
<th class="new">
<label>
<img alt="" src="images/green001/agree.gif"/>
<img alt="本版置顶" src="images/green001/pin_1.gif"/>
                                                             </label>
<em>[<a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=230&amp;filter=type&amp;typeid=1215">痴女</a>]</em> <span id="thread_10432064"><a href="thread-10432064-1-1.html" style="font-weight: bold;color: blue">(セレブの友)(CESD-???)大槻ひびき</a></span>
<img alt="附件" class="attach" src="images/attachicons/common.gif"/>
<span class="threadpages"> <img src="images/new2.gif"/></span>  ### new sticker
</th>
<td class="author"> ### author sticker
<cite>
<a href="space.php?action=viewpro&amp;uid=12737809">新片</a><img align="absmiddle" border="0" src="images/thankyou.gif"/>12                                       </cite>
<em>2019-4-23</em> ### date sticker
</td>
<td class="nums"><strong>6</strong> / <em>14398</em></td>
<td class="nums">7.29G / MP4                
                </td>
<td class="lastpost">
<em><a href="redirect.php?tid=10432064&amp;goto=lastpost#lastpost">2019-4-25 14:11</a></em>
<cite>by <a href="space.php?action=viewpro&amp;username=22811">22811</a></cite>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody><!-- 三級置頂分開 -->
```

Let's put it this way, it seems that I didn't express myself well enough. What i'm saying is this: for example, I wanna find all 'tbody' with either 'author' of 新片, or 'date' of 2019-4-23, or with a sticker called "images/new2.gif". I would get a lists of tbodys presumably, and then, I wanna find the href in them via

```
blue = soup.find_all('a', style="font-weight: bold;color: blue")
```

Thanks chiefs!

Comment: what do you mean by new stickers?  what would be the expected return value(s) for the above?

Comment: Can you mentioned your desire output as well in original post

Comment: Is your html properly formed?

Comment: There is a new class. .new - can't you just test for that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a class `new` so I am wondering if you could just use that? That would be:

```
items = soup.select('tbody:has(.new)')
for item in items:
    print([i['href'] for i in item.select('a')])
```

---

Otherwise, you can use `:has` and `:contains` pseudo classes (bs4 4.7.1) to specify those patterns

```
items = soup.select('tbody:has(.author a:contains("新片")), tbody:has(em:contains("2019-4-23")), tbody:has([src="images/new2.gif"])')
```

You can then get hrefs with a loop

```
for item in items:
    print([i['href'] for i in item.select('a')])
```

Comment: I just updated my question, chief, see if i made my self more clear about what I am looking for.

Comment: I will give it a try tonight, and see how it goes, :has :contains seems pretty neat. =D

Comment: Sure. Also, look at what I said about .new

Comment: Remove the commas to make it And. Though you don’t need to repeat tbody if that is the case

Comment: thx chief, these are so helpful, and I am having lots fun with new stuff. One thing I finds is that, all these 'tbody' criteria listed are 'or's to each other, not 'and's with each other. Is there a way to switch with one another? For example, I want new post which is published by "新片"

Comment: ic, let me give it a try and see how it goes

Comment: I might need to test it myself to get it exactly right

Comment: `items = soup.select('tbody:has(.new .author a:contains("新片"))')`
returned [], it seems i have more to work with, =D

Comment: i just tried chief, the magic marker is "+", "+" is "and" condition, "," is "or" condition.

Comment: for making the research effort +1

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out the parent tag  and then need to find the next sibling  and then find the respective tag.Hope you will get your answer.try below code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
data='''<tbody id="stickthread_10432064">
<tr>
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10432064-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
<td class="icon">
                                                                    </td>
<th class="new">
<label>
<img alt="" src="images/green001/agree.gif"/>
<img alt="本版置顶" src="images/green001/pin_1.gif"/>
                                                             </label>
<em>[<a href="forumdisplay.php?fid=230&amp;filter=type&amp;typeid=1215">痴女</a>]</em> <span id="thread_10432064"><a href="thread-10432064-1-1.html" style="font-weight: bold;color: blue">(セレブの友)(CESD-???)大槻ひびき</a></span>
<img alt="附件" class="attach" src="images/attachicons/common.gif"/>
<span class="threadpages"> <img src="images/new2.gif"/></span>  ### new sticker
</th>
<td class="author"> ### author sticker
<cite>
<a href="space.php?action=viewpro&amp;uid=12737809">新片</a><img align="absmiddle" border="0" src="images/thankyou.gif"/>12                                       </cite>
<em>2019-4-23</em> ### date sticker
</td>
<td class="nums"><strong>6</strong> / <em>14398</em></td>
<td class="nums">7.29G / MP4                
                </td>
<td class="lastpost">
<em><a href="redirect.php?tid=10432064&amp;goto=lastpost#lastpost">2019-4-25 14:11</a></em>
<cite>by <a href="space.php?action=viewpro&amp;username=22811">22811</a></cite>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('img',src=re.compile('images/new')):
    parent=item.parent.parent
    print(parent.find_next_siblings('td')[0].find('a').text)
    print(parent.find_next_siblings('td')[0].find('em').text)
```

Comment: let me give it a shot later today, and see how it goes, thx chief!